# Match multiline PCRE until an exception

Tags: regex, pcre

Is it possible to use a regex to generate matches until a pattern is broken?

https://regex101.com/r/bRQkWM/1

```
(?m)(?=.*?\*)(\d+)|\*\w*.*$
```

In this instance, capture the digits at the start of the line, plus the rest of the line **provided** the line begins with a `*`.

If the line does not begin with a `*`, do not match digits or rest of line.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But then why last line that starts with `162 *` should not be matched?

Comment: I wish to group the matches until an exception occurs. 

Imagine that each line which contains no * is the title of a book. The subsequent lines containing a * would be the chapters of said book. I want to stop the match when the next book title appears, so that the 'chapter' matches are limited to the book in question.

Hope that helps clarify!

Comment: Can you try this https://regex101.com/r/bRQkWM/2 and see if this works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be ([link](https://regex101.com/r/7kH3Ea/2)):

```
(?m)\G(\d+)\s+\*(\w*.*)(?:[\n\r]+|$)
```

However... The example you provided has broken pattern right in its first line, as there is no `*` in such line. That leads me to a conclusion that you wish to ignore all lines before the fist match. If that is your desired specification, then the solution should be ([link](https://regex101.com/r/bLbc5L/2)):

```
(?m)\A(?:\d+\s+[^*]\w*.*$[\n\r]*)*|\G(\d+)\s+\*(\w*.*)(?:[\n\r]+|$)
```

This extended regex pattern will work even if there is no broken pattern before the first match.

Please keep in mind that the first match of this solution has to be ignored, as it contains those ignored lines before the first match, or it is empty if there are no lines needed to be ignored.

---

The key of the above solution(s) is a use of `\G`, the anchor that matches at the position where the previous match ended.